# PHP Charset for special characters

Tags: php, html

I am creating my website with HTML and PHP with a post function. In the post, I am using special special characters (Å, Á ...), but they appear as � on the screen. However, all of the HTML content works.

Any idea?

```
<META http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">


<?php
getPosts();

?>
```

And the Functions file:

```
<?php
include('connect.php');

function getPosts() {
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM posts") or die(mysql_error());
    while($post = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
        echo "<h2>" . $post['Title'] . " by " . $post['Author'] . "</h2>";
        echo $post['Content'];

    }
}
?>
```

Comment: you have to ensure that your ENTIRE rendering pipeline is set to utf-8. Just because your webpage is doesn't mean that the php<->mysql connection is, or the tables within mysql.

Comment: Maybe try using the ASCII equivalent?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure your MySQL character set and collation (at least for this database/table/column) is utf8.
Also make sure that you set the connection charset correctly:

```
mysql_set_charset ( "utf8" );
```

This requires PHP 5.2.3 and MySQL 5.0.7. Also consider switching to MySQLi or PDO which usually handles this better. The obsolete mysql_* API has been deprecated in PHP 5.5

Answer (score 1):

chances are your mySQL database table is not in the correct collation.

```
ALTER TABLE `posts` CHANGE `content` `content` TEXT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL ;
```

do a change like this for your entire database, table, or cell.

Comment: The storage character set is actually very likely irrelevant here: it merely limits (or not) the range of characters that will be stored. The collation controls string matching and ordering and won't affect the characters stored or returned to the client.